# CakePHP 1.3, Form Helper and Self Joined Table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My Self Joined Categories table is as follows:

```
id, name, description, parent_id
```

I used Cake Bake to generate the Model, Controller and Views. Model
has the $belongsTo and $hasMany association set up. In add() of the
controller,

```
$parentCategories = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find('list');
$this->set(compact('parentCategories'));
```

is present. In the add view, the cake bake generated form is:

```
<?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('isincome');
        echo $this->Form->input('parent_id');
?>
```

When I run in browser, the parent_id field is getting a drop down, but
it is not being filled with any data. I used

```
<?debug($parentCategories);?>
```

in the add view, and it happily outputs

```
Array
(
    [1] => Entertainment
    [2] => Groceries
)
```

But this array is not being used for filling that drop down by the
Form helper. What should I do? Is this a bug with Cake's Form helper in 1.3? It never occurred in 1.2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding an input for `field_id`, the form helper looks for a variable called `$fields`. I.e., the name without `_id` and pluralized. `$parentCategories` does not fit that description, so it's not used. `$parents` would be.

Second, `$this->Category->ParentCategory` is the same as `$this->Category`. Both reference the Category model. No need to go through `ParentCategory`.

Third, it's not usually a good idea to join a Tree model to itself. You'll understand why when you start to query with higher `recursive` settings. You should instead make it a [proper Tree](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1339/Tree) and use the TreeBehavior methods to query it.

Comment: Thanks deceze, it worked! But I wonder why bake generated such output then.. What ever I posted above is cake bake generated code!

Comment: @Asok That's why you don't self-join a model, bake doesn't handle it very gracefully. :)

Comment: The link for proper Tree is no longer valid.